# Accidentally deleted .csproj files. Solution now not finding half my project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

3 commits ago I had accidentally deleted a few .csproj files from my project. Later, when I went to clean and rebuild the solution, I noticed it was only finding half the project files (37 of 66).

I am using git. I reset my branch back to the commit just before I deleted these files. I can find the csproj files and all related code in my file explorer within that project, but the solution explorer in visual studio still is not finding them or all the related code. I was told resetting to this commit should fix it and VS should itself after opening back up but no luck. Is there another way I can go / do I have this all wrong?

Comment: Which command did you use to reset? Did you use the `--hard` flag? Is the sln file modified from the `git status` command? If you view the sln file with a text editor, does it have all the entries and paths you expect?

Comment: I did use the —hard command. I’ll check on the sln file shortly. I had also created a separate branch before I deleted anything to be safe. Switching to that branch isn’t helping either.

Comment: Ensure you have "Show All Files" enabled in solution explorer. It sounds like the files are there , but removed from the project, if they are visible in file explorer.

Comment: I do have that as well. I think this question can be closed though. I was just told other coworkers were having the same issue and that it’s due to a TDS subscription expiration.